# Some tumblr posts not showing up properly on custom theme

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I'm new to this site, so apologies for any mistakes. I make themes on Tumblr, and I'm having a problem with [certain](https://angelicdigital.tumblr.com/post/647574588894674944) [kinds](https://angelicdigital.tumblr.com/post/647566425776619520) of [posts](https://angelicdigital.tumblr.com/post/647380400321314816) not showing up properly inside the theme itself. As you can see from the posts, the images aren't loading at all.

I thought it might be something wrong with photosets in my theme, but fiddling with those did nothing. I'm honestly kind of a novice at HTML and CSS so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the bits of CSS/HTML I think might be the issue.

```
.media{
margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

iframe, img, embed, object, video {
   max-width: 100%;
}

img {
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
{block:Photo}
<center><div class="media">{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></div></center>{LinkCloseTag}
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
<div class="media">{Photoset}</div>
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

If it helps at all, I use the base theme by [Animecharacter](https://pastebin.com/EwSLv2pY) as the building blocks for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like css `position: absolute` is causing the images to be removed form the flow of the document, and not have any height or width properties set.

At the bottom of your theme inside the `style` tag (usually towards the end).

```
.post-content div.npf_row .npf_col figure img, 
.post div.npf_row .npf_col figure img, 
body div.npf_row .npf_col figure img {
   position: static;
}
```

See screenshot attached where I disabled the position property.

If that does not work you can override the property from the external stylesheet by doing this:

```
.post-content div.npf_row .npf_col figure img, 
.post div.npf_row .npf_col figure img, 
body div.npf_row .npf_col figure img {
   position: static !important;
}
```

But this is less preferential it's better to find at what stage in your template this is being applied and write your css after that block (if possible)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The images appear now but the space between them is huge, and they're also clipping into the blockquote but I'm just glad this is fixed now.

Comment: If you Inspect Element in Chrome (or other browsers) you can see the css properties for page in the RH panel. From here you can change, add or remove properties just to see how it will look, and then implement these in your template.